# getting "NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE: prompt aborted by user" in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

While calling the below function from HTML form tag (`<form method="post" onsubmit="ajacxpost(this.form)">`) then, getting an **error like:** `"NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE: prompt aborted by user"`

Please help me to solve this..

```
    function ajacxpost(form){
    var password=$("#password").val();
    var userId=$("#userId").val();
    var json={"userId":userId,"password":password};
    $.ajax({    
        type:"Post",
        url:"login/login.html",
        data:JSON.stringify(json),
        success: function(response){
            if(response.status=="success"){
                alert("You are Registered");
            }
            else{
                alert("Something went Wrong");
            }

        },
        error:function(e){
            alert("error"+e.status);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: prevent default form submit..!

Answer (score 0):

Most Probably, because this is a `POST`, you need to `return false;` for your form submit. 
Place this just before closing brace of the function and let me know if it works.